# Using MDMA for buffer manipulation on STM32H743vit

Tags: stm32, dma

I have buffer `buff[BUFFER_SIZE]`, I want to fill it with data from random generator peripheral. Then the copy must increment equal to BUFFER_SIZE. After calling DMA generator with specified number to be transfer, all data will become full. I can't do this since random number generator or RNG can't generate numbers too fast, then I want to copy data to `buff` after each DMA event using DMA generator. And the specified data must be counted down for DMA to know where reset the destination address. I don't want interrupt and CPU intervention, I think it must not be possible with DMA generator, is it possible to do this with MDMA, what is its approach?

[image]

More detail on question:

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001YdcPbSAJ/create-array-of-random-number-without-cpu-intervention-for-blocked-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found: we don't need MDMA. This is easily possible with DMA request generator with synchronization signal to create vector of random numbers from RNG peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

The random number generator only supports interrupts, so has no mechanism to signal to any DMA controller when a new value is available.

One way to do it is of course to set up a timer to generate DMA request events to trigger a DMA transfer from RNG data register to memory. But timer rate must be done at a slow enough rate that the RNG is known to have generated new data.

If you want to generate random numbers fast, then there are better mechanisms than to wait for the slow RNG to generate truely random numbers slowly.

Comment: If you don't want to use DMA to read RNG numbers to memory buffer without CPU intervention, then I don't understand your question. DMA is used to transfer data from somewhere to somewhere without CPU handlig the transfer. So what do you want to do then, do you want to copy data blocks with memory to memory with DMA? You can't "create" buffers with DMA, or what do you mean by creating buffers?

Comment: I want to use DMA or MDMA. I dont want to copy from one word to other. The question is to copy from one word to sequence of word. I think DMA can not copy the 32-bit to 16*32bit in step by step after each DMA request. DMA copy 16 times from 32 to 16*32, this can not be done because RNG can't. I asked how to do this with DMA or MDMA (Note: DMA request is not forced to be derived from RNG peripheral it has been derived from DMA request generator with slow enoupgh rate, then this is not a problem)?

Comment: Yes but it is unclear what you want to do with DMA here. You can copy data, or fill, at full bandwidth. You can't read with DMA from RNG as RNG cannot trigger DMA transfer. You can use a timer to generate DMA transfer triggers at slow enough rate where it is guaranteed that RNG has data available to be read and stored to memory with DMA.

Comment: Yes it can handle it. That is what DMA is for. Moving data from peripherals to memory buffer with certain size.

Comment: Certain size is ok but this is a burst, this seuences every word must being filled with only one request step by step. not to fill all with only one request.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. Each data fetched from peripheral is stored sequentially into buffer. That is what DMA does.

Comment: imagine two scenario: 1) one request occure dmacopy from RNG 8 time to fill array of size 8, each time request happen the process repeat. 2) one request happen DMA copy one time from RNG to array element one, the increment destination adress then do nothing, by secound request it again reads RNG and fill the secound element of array, after 8 request array will be filled, DMA reset destination adress to it's reference. by next request process repeat. Does DMA can handle these two scenario?

Comment: No it can't because RNG cannot do DMA requests.

Comment: As you told we can use timer(or many existing campatible thing) to generate DMA request.

Comment: Could you please delete your answer? since  I want to delete my question. I have found the answer but I think this will not contribute since it have only 98  view.